# Django M2M with a large table

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a typical M2M scenario where promotion activities are related to our retailers. However we have a large number of retailers (over 10k) and therefore I can't use the normal multiple select widget.

What I would aim to do is have an 'activity' instance page with a 'retailer' sub-page which would have a table listing all those retailers currently related to the activity. In addition there would be a 'delete' checkbox next to each retailer so they could be removed from the list if necessary. (Naturally, I would also have another search/results page where users could select which retailers they want to add to the list, but I'm sure I can sort that out myself).

Could someone point me in the right direction regarding modelforms and formset factories as I'm not sure where to go from here. It would seem obvious to directly manipulate the app_activity_associated_retailers table but I don't think I can do this with the existing functions. Is there was a pattern for doing this.

```
class Activity(models.Model):
    budget = models.ForeignKey('Budget')
    activity_type = models.ForeignKey('ActivityType')
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    associated_retailers = models.ManyToManyField('Retailer', related_name='associated_retailers')

class Retailer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    address01 = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    address02 = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    postcode = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All `ManyToManyField`s have a `through` model, whether you define one yourself or not. In your case, it'll have an `id`, an `activity` field and a `retailer` field. You can access the table with `Activity.associated_retailers.through` -- one "obvious" way is to just expose it as a "model" like

```
ActivityRetailer = Activity.associated_retailers.through
```

You can now manipulate these relationships like they were any ol' Django model, so you can i.e. generate querysets like

```
retailer_records_for_activity = ActivityRetailer.objects.filter(activity_id=1234)
```

... and you can also create model formsets (complete with that `delete` checkbox if so configured) for these pseudo-models.

Comment: Thanks for that, I hadn't thought of doing it that way. For whatever reason I couldn't get that first command to work as: 
'ManyToManyField' object has no attribute 'through'. 
It is possible that it's because the client is still using Django 1.1 (despite me wanting to upgrade it), so I exposed the through table within the models by specifying the db_table and fields.

Comment: @alj Oh, dammit, my bad! I had the wrong syntax for accessing the table. Fixed that. Anyway, glad you got things working – and you really oughta maybe upgrade that Django at some point... 1.1 has been EOL for a long while.

Comment: Yep, I know ... really need upgrade. 
BTW Activity.associated_retailers.through = 'ReverseManyRelatedObjectsDescriptor' object has no attribute 'through'

Comment: Okay. Well, that I'll pin on Django 1.1 then, it works on the 2.x installation I have at hand ;)